# MySql variable stored with select count statement always returns 1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hello in a test database i have only one row in the table customer.I have created a stored procedure to do some work. Every time i execute this query

```
  select count(*) from Customer where Email= ....
```

in my database i get a count 0 but in my stored procedure the result is always 1 without any error.This is the code inside my stored procedure.

```
  BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
  SET @var=(select count(*) from Customer where Email=email);
  select @var;
  if (@var>0) then
    update Customer Set Password=temppass,TemporaryPassword=temppass where 
    Email=email;
    COMMIT;
  ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
  END
```

Any ideas please?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your condition `Email = email`.  This is always going to be true -- because both references to `email` are referring to the same thing, the `email` column in the table.

Call the variable by a different name.  I often use the suffix `v_`, so `where customer.email = v_email`.

That said, I think you can just do:

```
begin
    update Customer c
        set c.Password = v_temppass,
            c.TemporaryPassword = v_temppass
    where c.email = v_email;
end;
```

I don't see what value the transaction gives.

I assume that you are not storing passwords as clear-text.  That is definitely a no-no if you care at all about security and access.

Comment: It worked!By the way the passwords are encrypted because i really care about security and access.Thank you very much!